# How do I get a key from file matching a pattern in bash, split by =, but where value also can contain =

Tags: bash

I'm reading from a file and want to

1. Get the text for value where key = "key".

   i.e.
   key = value
2. Trim any white space around the value or the key

However, value can also contain an = because it's a base64 encoded field.

I've been using this previously:

```
key=`egrep 'key' myfile | cut -f2 -d'=' | sed 's/ //g'`
```

But, cut works globally.  Is there a way of making it work on just the first item?

Or perhaps there more efficient way of doing this.

e.g. if myfile = ceph.client.keyring

```
[client.admin]
    key = AQAa6HRVaDKxLxAANulnamD/5x2SBly7kPPatg==
    auid = 0
    caps mds = "allow"
    caps mon = "allow *"
    caps osd = "allow *"
```

I'm wanting to read into a variable the value for key (AQAa6HRVaDKxLxAANulnamD/5x2SBly7kPPatg==)

Comment: Show some sample input and corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using sed

Your your example `myfile`:

```
$ sed -rn '/^[[:space:]]*key[ =]/ s/[^=]*=[[:space:]]*//p' myfile
AQAa6HRVaDKxLxAANulnamD/5x2SBly7kPPatg==
```

How it works:

- `sed -rn`

  This tells sed to use extended regular expressions, `-r`, and not to print unless we explicitly ask it to, `-n`.
- `/^[[:space:]]*key[ =]/`

  This selects lines that optionally start with whitespace, followed by `key`, followed by either a blank or an equal sign, `=`.
- `s/[^=]*=[[:space:]]*//p`

  For those selected lines, this strips out everything before the first equal sign and any whitespace after the equal sign.  The `p` option tells sed to print the resulting line.

### Using awk

This assumes that, as in your example, the first equal sign is surrounded by spaces **and that the value for key contains no whitespace**:

```
$ awk '$1=="key"{print $3}' myfile
AQAa6HRVaDKxLxAANulnamD/5x2SBly7kPPatg==
```

How it works:

- `$1=="key"`

  This selects lines whose first field is `key`.
- `{print $3}`

  For those selected lines, this prints the third field.

#### Alternate sed solution

Doing the selecting and substituting in one step:

```
$ sed -rn 's/^[[:space:]]*key[[:space:]]=[[:space:]]*//p' myfile
AQAa6HRVaDKxLxAANulnamD/5x2SBly7kPPatg==
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` with Perl regex:

```
grep -oP "(?<=\skey\s=\s)[^\s]*" file
```

Output:

```
AQAa6HRVaDKxLxAANulnamD/5x2SBly7kPPatg==
```

Note: It assumes there's only one white space between `key` and `=`, & `=` and `value`

Or using `sed`:

```
sed -nr 's/.*\skey\s*=\s*([^\s]*).*/\1/p' file
AQAa6HRVaDKxLxAANulnamD/5x2SBly7kPPatg==
```